# audio not working amd ryzen

Tags: sound

I've been searching for 2 days multiple solutions and multiple forums but I can't resolve this problem

I'm new to ubuntu but i learned to use the terminal. When i installed ubuntu on my amd ryzen there was no output device, then after I follow some guides turned to dummy output and now recognize the output audio but still not working

please help!

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013 E13 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lucienne (rev c2)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 01)
```

```
lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
taro-bom-wxx9               
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 7680MiB
     *-cpu
          product: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 23.104.1
          size: 2445MHz
          capacity: 4056MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd cppc arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip rdpid overflow_recov succor smca cpufreq
          configuration: microcode=140542211
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-generic UNCLAIMED
             description: IOMMU
             product: Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 0.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:00.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:34 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:d0500000-d05fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlp1s0
                version: 00
                serial: 94:08:53:56:2e:63
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=5.19.0-23-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.8.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:74 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0500000-d050ffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:35 memory:d0400000-d04fffff
           *-nvme
                description: NVMe device
                product: 311CD0512GB
                vendor: Phison Electronics Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: /dev/nvme0
                version: EDFOB0.7
                serial: 511210820127039811
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: nvme nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0 nqn=nqn.2014.08.org.nvmexpress:19871987511210820127039811  311CD0512GB state=live
                resources: irq:56 memory:d0400000-d0403fff
              *-namespace:0
                   description: NVMe disk
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: hwmon3
              *-namespace:1
                   description: NVMe disk
                   physical id: 2
                   logical name: /dev/ng0n1
              *-namespace:2
                   description: NVMe disk
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: nvme@0:1
                   logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
                   configuration: wwid=eui.6479a754e0901ed6
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 8.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:36 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:d0000000-d03fffff ioport:fce0000000(size=270532608)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Lucienne
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: /dev/fb0
                version: c2
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
                configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
                resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:47 memory:fce0000000-fcefffffff memory:fcf0000000-fcf01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d0300000-d037ffff
           *-multimedia:0
                description: Audio device
                product: Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
                logical name: card0
                logical name: controlC0
                logical name: hwC0D0
                logical name: pcmC0D3p
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:72 memory:d03c0000-d03c3fff
              *-input
                   product: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: input12
                   logical name: /dev/input/event8
           *-generic
                description: Encryption controller
                product: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=ccp latency=0
                resources: irq:66 memory:d0200000-d02fffff memory:d03c4000-d03c5fff
           *-usb:0
                description: USB controller
                product: Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.3
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:38 memory:d0000000-d00fffff
           *-usb:1
                description: USB controller
                product: Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.4
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.4
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:47 memory:d0100000-d01fffff
           *-multimedia:1
                description: Multimedia controller
                product: ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.5
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.5
                logical name: card1
                logical name: controlC1
                logical name: pcmC1D0c
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_rn_pci_acp3x latency=0
                resources: irq:70 memory:d0380000-d03bffff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: FCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 51
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: FCH LPC Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 51
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
           *-pnp00:00
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 0
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:01
                product: PnP device PNP0b00
                physical id: 1
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
           *-pnp00:02
                product: PnP device PNP0303
                physical id: 2
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
           *-pnp00:03
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 3
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:04
                product: PnP device PNP0c01
                physical id: 4
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir Device 24: Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir Device 24: Function 1
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir Device 24: Function 2
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir Device 24: Function 3
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir Device 24: Function 4
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 108
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:9
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir Device 24: Function 5
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 109
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:10
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir Device 24: Function 6
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10a
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.6
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:11
          description: Host bridge
          product: Renoir Device 24: Function 7
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10b
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.7
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
  *-input:0
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 1
       logical name: input0
       logical name: /dev/input/event0
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:1
       product: Lid Switch
       physical id: 2
       logical name: input1
       logical name: /dev/input/event1
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:2
       product: HD Camera: HD Camera
       physical id: 3
       logical name: input11
       logical name: /dev/input/event7
       capabilities: usb
  *-input:3
       product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
       physical id: 4
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       logical name: input2::capslock
       logical name: input2::numlock
       logical name: input2::scrolllock
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:4
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: 5
       logical name: input3
       logical name: /dev/input/event3
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:5
       product: Huawei WMI hotkeys
       physical id: 6
       logical name: input7
       logical name: /dev/input/event4
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:6
       product: GXTP7863:00 27C6:01E0 Mouse
       physical id: 7
       logical name: input8
       logical name: /dev/input/event5
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
       capabilities: i2c
  *-input:7
       product: GXTP7863:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad
       physical id: 8
       logical name: input9
       logical name: /dev/input/event6
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
       capabilities: i2c
```

thank you

---

Update:

I changed 3 different linux distro (ubuntu, lubuntu and mint) and the problem is always dummy output

so this is a general problem with linux and my driver audio

any suggestion?

---

update

It could be useful to download drivers from the amd website?

thank you for your help

---

Thank you for your reply!

Yes all the distro I used were the newest possible

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le ch 2 44100 Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 12
    properties:
        device.description = "Uscita dummy"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could share the output of `pacmd list-sinks`.
You may want to use a live cd of a recent distro, such as Manjaro/EndeavourOS/Ubuntu 22.10/Fedora 37, a newer kernel helps with newer hardware.